# Unique permutations rearangement letters (which contain duplicates)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

Now I've been asked how many ways there are to rearrange the letter combination "L L L B B C C C".

Obviously you would say this is $8!$, because you would have $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot1$ possibilities to order these letters. But what if you swap two L's and consider that not as a unique permutation but as a duplicate?

Now somehow it seems quite logical to divide the amount of permutations by the amount of duplicates, factorial, multiplied with each other. So $\dfrac{8!}{3!2!3!}$ which turns out to be 560.

But I am not really sure if this is correct. I consider it to be correct, because it works if I simplify the problem by looking for unique permutations with the letters "L L B B", which is 6 and $\dfrac{4!}{2!2!}$ turns out te be 6.

But I need some more proof. Can somebody give me a better explanation why this is true and the way to go or this still isn't the right solution?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of combinations or the number of permutations?

Comment: Well actually neither, really. As a shorter example: in case of L L A B . I am looking for L L B A as well. So no combinations you would say. But swapping L counts as a permutation, but visually it's also a duplicate. And I don't want to count those duplicates

Comment: You are looking for proof that the multinomial coefficient is equal to the factorial of the total number of letters divided by the product of factorials of the amount of repetition of each of the letters?  You should at this point be comfortable with that $\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ (*and if not, you should be asking about that first*).  Notice that you can describe a multinomial coefficient as a product of binomial coefficients.  Here, $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}$ which does indeed equal $\dfrac{8!}{3!2!3!}$ after simplifications.

Comment: The combinatorial explanation being, to arrange three identical $L$'s, two identical $B$'s and three identical $C$'s in a row, you can first choose which of the spaces are occupied by $L$'s simultaneously, then choose which of the remaining spaces are occupied by $B$'s, and then which of those still remaining are occupied by $C$'s.  This generalizes of course to any scenario so long as you are still using all of the available letters of each type.

Comment: You could also have justified this by way of a "division by symmetry" sort of argument, having looked at how much you had overcounted each scenario... but those sort of arguments are often avoided as they are not seen as being particularly "elegant."

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation JMoravitz! Well I'm not comfortable with the formula you just showed me. I'm taking a pre-calculus class (never had calculus in schoool before), but guess I am too far ahead already. Guess I should be more patient. We are just discussing permutations, combinations and different scenarios. This was a question which striked me, but guess I need more background if I understand correctly. But thanks again!

Comment: Aaand we just get to the binomial coefficient formula you showed me, now the formula at least makes sense, lol. I will save all of this in my bookmarks and have a look back later on

Comment: I just multiplied all binomial coefficients and after canceling all numerators and denominators I do get my result indeed....